# Only allow document to be read if ID is known

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection named `proposals`, which I want to disable listing on it and allow only get if user know the ID.

Is it possible with Firebase?

My currently fails because "read" is allowed, but without this I can't read the document.

```
match /proposals/{uid} {
  allow list, update, delete: if false;

  allow create, read: if true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty common to do this kind of authorization, and yes, it's possible.
Firestore Security Rules provide to us `request.auth.uid` which contains the UID of the user making the request or null if it's unauthenticated.

So, you could use that information with an equality operator:

```
match /proposals/{uid} {
  allow list, update, delete: if false;

  // Allow getting Documents if the Document ID is equal to the currently uid of the authenticated user who is making the request.
  allow get: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
  allow create;
}
```

You should use `get` to define rules that will apply when any user is trying to *get a document*. Note that `read` is for *any type of read request*, which includes `get` and `list`.

More about Security Rules and Authentication: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth

Comment: Reading comprehension uid != id

Comment: `request.auth.uid == uid` Will only allow read document with equal value as user ID.